# NoReverseMatch at / Reverse for 'new_url' with no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['new/(?P<spk>[0-9]+)/\\Z']

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-forms

Can't resolve this error.
The idea is that after the form that the user fills out, he goes to the page by PK, where the data that he entered is located

*views.py*

```
# Form
class GetUser(FormView):
    form_class = PersonForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('new_url')
    template_name = 'party/home.html'

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if request.method == 'POST':
            form = PersonForm(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                cd = form.cleaned_data

                pc = Person(name=cd.get('name'), last_name=cd.get('last_name'))
                pc.save()
        return redirect(self.success_url)

# DetailView
class UserNew(DetailView):
    model = Person
    template_name = 'party/show.html'
    context_object_name = 'new_user'

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Person.objects.filter(pk=self.kwargs['pk'])
```

*models.py*

```
class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150, verbose_name='Імʼя')
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=150, verbose_name='Прізвище')
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, verbose_name='created_at')

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.name} {self.last_name}'

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('person', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Person'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Person'
        ordering = ['-created_at']
```

*html*

```
<body>
    <div>
        <h1>Привіт</h1>
    </div>

    <form action="{% url 'home_url' %}" method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.as_p }}

        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Let`s go</button>
    </form>

</body>
```

*urls.py*

```
urlpatterns = [
    # path('', get_user, name='home_url'),
    path('', GetUser.as_view(), name='home_url'),
    path('all', UserAll.as_view(), name='all_url'),
    path('new/<int:pk>/', UserNew.as_view(), name='new_url'),
]
```

I tried rewriting views.py, urls.py, but nothing works

Comment: What is `success_url = reverse_lazy('new_url')` supposed to do? Share your urls.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The error is happening because in your url, you have defined that it will have additional parameters, maybe like this

```
path('new/<int:pk>', SomeView.as_view(), name='new_url')
```

Thus, the url should look like `localhost:8000/new/123`. But when you are using `reverse_lazy`, you are not passing the parameters (spk value), hence it is causing the problem. But you can fix it like this:

```
class GetUser(FormView):
    form_class = PersonForm
    template_name = 'party/home.html'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        cleaned_data = form.cleaned_data
        person = Person(name=cd.get('name'), last_name=cd.get('last_name'))
        person.save()
        return redirect('new_url', spk=person.pk)
```

More information can be found in the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/class-based-views/generic-editing/#basic-forms).